# Using @wip to skip certain data lines

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

So I am wondering if there is a way to skip certain rows for a cucumber data table. Lets say given this example (taken from cucumbers website)

```
Scenario Outline: feeding a suckler cow
  Given the cow weighs <weight> kg
  When we calculate the feeding requirements
  Then the energy should be <energy> MJ
  And the protein should be <protein> kg

  Examples:
    | weight | energy | protein |
    |    450 |  26500 |     215 |
    |    500 |  29500 |     245 |
    |    575 |  31500 |     255 |
    |    600 |  37000 |     305 |
```

I want to only skip the 2nd data line (weight:500..). Is this possible? If currently not, where can I find the cucumber tags and add my own custom ones? I would love for a soltion like @wipR2 @wipR4 where R2 and R4 mean row 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do  this by splitting up your examples table into two and using @wip tag on one of them. Then run the test with the negate wip tag - ~@wip in 'tags' options to filter in cucumberoptions.

```
Examples:
    | weight | energy | protein |
    |    450 |  26500 |     215 |
    |    575 |  31500 |     255 |
    |    600 |  37000 |     305 |

  @wip
  Examples:
    | weight | energy | protein |
    |    500 |  29500 |     245 |
```

Comment: cucumberoptions? Is this a file somewhere I can alter, or a setting?

Comment: My bad. Did not see the cucumberjs tag in your question and mentioned the cucumber java style. You need to pass the ~@wip to the tags option to the command that starts cucumber. Basically you are filtering out this tag.

Comment: If it negates the @wip tag, then wont it still run the split off section? And no worries, I am sure it is a similar solution :)

Comment: You need to look at it as filtering. In this case if you do not include any tag filter both the example tables will be run. If you use '@wip' then only the scenarios in the annotated '@wip' table will run. But you need the opposite behaviour. So you use '~@wip' which runs the non-annotated table only. Look at the command line options - https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner

Comment: Ok, so this is what my cucumberoptions tags looks like tags = ['~@wip']. Just this, or do we need another @wip without the ~